# How do I use adb command to save top results?

Tags: android, grep, adb

I want to save the results of "top | grep applicationX" into file in windows. I can save the top results using adb shell top > C:\top_result.txt but I need to use grep. So, i am doing:

adb shell
top | grep applicationX

I am getting the information that I want in the terminal, but I want to save it into a file. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: you can refer to BIC's answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488211/log-adb-top-to-file-in-windows-cygwin

Answer (score 0):

`adb shell top | grep applicationX > C:\top_result.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You could manipulate the output like this:

`adb shell top | grep applicationX > /dir/somefile`