# log adb top to file in windows cygwin

Tags: android, windows, cygwin, adb

Trying to log cpu usage (to file) of my app under windows.

First I tried this usning cmd

```
adb shell top | grep com.myapp > log.log
```

Which gives "grep is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.". I guess windows doesn't any grep command?

Then I tried the same command usning cygwin terminal. This resulted in an **empty logfile**. So I ran the same command but without redirecting the output

```
adb shell top | grep com.myapp
```

This **returned the expected output**. I've also tried redirecting stderr with "2>&1". Didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have got the same problem and --line-buffered solved it.

For example

`adb shell top | grep --line-buffered com.myapp > log.log`